# Creating satellite assemblies using Al.exe

Tags: .net, localization, resources, satellite-assembly

I am trying to create satellite assemblies using Al.exe.

To create an assembly from a `.ressources` file I am executing the following command:

```
al.exe /c:<culture> /out:<output dll name> /embedresource: <name of the .resources file> /fileversion:3.1.5.0 /productv:3.1.5.0 /keyf:Key.snk
```

**First question:**

Do the fileversion, productv and keyf must be the same as the file version, product version and key of my deployed application?

**Second question:**

Why when I deploy the generated DLLs to the GAC the version column become 0.0.0.0 ? But when I view their properties in the GAC why the file version and the product version are correct and the version field is 0.0.0.0?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to question 1:**

It seems that file version, product version and key must be the same as the deployed application or the satellite Dll will not be visible and the application will use the default resource Dll.

**Answer to question 2:**

The version is 0.0.0.0 because the is a `/v` option when using the Al.exe that must be specified in addition to the file and product versions.

**Best Method:**

The best way is to use the `/template` option instead of individually specifying the version, file version and product version so the newly created assembly can inherit the correct manifest from the application assemblies.